# Perl `defined`function complexity

Tags: perl

I have a perl script, which is accepting a list of arguments(mandatory and non-mandatory). Based on these args flow of script is determined. Where i am confused is, if the arg(which is in the form of switch) is used multiple times in the script to determine flow(most of the time used in `if` loop), then which one is better
`if(defined arg){}`
OR
`my $switch = defined arg ? 1:0; if($switch){}`

Comment: This is not what you should be optimizing. Use whatever is most readable.

Comment: @ikegami Thanks for commenting.. I know this is too small to think in terms of optimizing. Just out of curiosity this came to my mind.

Comment: The second option adds complexity. `defined foo` already returns `1` (that's true) or `q{}` ( the empty string, which is false). All you need to do is make sure that your `arg` is allowed to be set and `0`, because it will still be `defined` in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`defined` already returns true or false. Using the result of `defined` to select a true value for true case and a false value for the false case is just extra work. This does all the work you need and no extra work:

```
if( defined $foo ) { ... }
```

Sometimes I want to print that true or false value, so I'll use the double bang (negate, and negate again) to normalize the value:

```
 !! defined $foo
```